# I am unable to view the contents of my website which I deployed on Firebase

Tags: html, firebase, web-hosting

I deployed a simple website (made using only HTML and a bit of CSS & JavaScript) which only contains a button. After the deployment I ran the project by copying the given domain on the web browser (Chrome in my case). But all I get is a welcome page with Firebase Hosting Setup Complete but I don't see my webpage.

#### This is the webpage I created

[image: This is the webpage I created]

#### This is what I get after deploying on firebase

[image: This is what I get after deploying on firebase]

Answer (score 2):

Its a common problem...

First check your `index.html`, if you have a build folder, your `index.html` should be the same as the `index.html` outside your build folder. (the name)
Second if you dont have build folder, the name of the entry point should be `index.html`, firebase its looking for it, if that is the case just rename it and deploy once again.
Third, delete `.firebase` and reinit it and after that deploy it once again.

Here is a long ref:
https://github.com/coreui/coreui-react/issues/55